# Java Spring : JDBC Connection getting closed

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, transactions, spring-aop

I'm working on project of Java with Spring JDBC and AOP transaction.
I have a scenario  in which I'm fetching huge data from one database and storing it in List> object, then I pass this data to "write" method which creates jdbc connection with another database and writes that huge data one by one. Writing takes time of around 10 minutes and then my code again tries to fetch some data from the first database as it tries to fetch data the previous object for the first database gets already closed therefore I get following exception :

TransactionInterceptor:542 - Application exception overridden by rollback exception

Note1: The first connection to the database is through spring bean file and second connection is created only when write method is called.

Note2 : This whole process is in one transaction (transaction on first database only [I don't need transaction on other database])

While writing huge that the first object remains idle and hence gets deleted and when again the code tries to fetch data it creates different connection object but my transaction contains the first connection object which is already closed therefore I'm getting this exception.

To overcome this I'm thinking to increase time out in my database.config file but I'm not sure that it is the time out problem only, if you think it is a time out problem please suggest me the code to increase connection time out in spring jdbc

I need your suggestion over this. Maybe I'm wrong. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that increasing the transaction timeout isn't a good idea in your case (honestly, almost never is). As it is just a workaround for the improper usage of transactions.

Transactions, by their design, should be as short as possible. So from my side, a suggested solution is to break the whole process into a couple of steps, and perform each in a different transaction.

BTW: your error message: `Application exception overridden by rollback exception` says that Spring couldn't perform transaction rollback. Please investigate this exception cause.

Comment: Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Connection ConnectionID:9 is closed. This is due to connection gets closed.

Comment: Good, then simply start a new transaction (Spring JDBC will acquire a new connection for you). You may also find the [Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html) helpful.